# Compilation doesnt work anymore (BibTex)

Tags: bibtex

I am getting this message once compiling my document:

```
BibTeX subsystem: /tmp/biber_tmp_feJh/f4d088b3f9f145b5c3058da33afd57d4_726414.utf8, 
line 102, syntax error: found "note", expected end of entry 
("}" or ")") (skipping to next "@")
```

I searched for any error in my `.bib` file and tried to change something but the same error keeps popping up. Do you know what I need to do?

The bibliography.bib entries that I am using:

```
@misc{statista1,
title={Simulationsspiele - Weltweit: Statista Marktprognose},
url={https://de.statista.com/outlook/dmo/app/spiele/simulationsspiele/weltweit},
author={Statista},
note={Online; abgerufen am 16.04.2023}
}

@misc{statista2,
title={Spiele - Weltweit: Statista Marktprognose},
url={https://de.statista.com/outlook/dmo/app/spiele/weltweit#umsatz},
author={Statista},
note={Online; abgerufen am 16.04.2023}
}

@misc{johannssen,
title={Simulations-Videospiele: Warum wollen alle so gerne Bauer sein?},
url={https://www.faz.net/aktuell/feuilleton/medien/warum-simulations-videospiele-so-beliebt-sind-18581485.html?printPagedArticle=true#pageIndex_3},
author={Johannssen, Philipp},
note={Online; abgerufen am 16.04.2023}
}

@misc{fwesi,
title={Über FwESI: Fwesi - Dokumentation},
url={https://docs.fwesi.de/docs/allgemein/about-fwesi/},
author={FwESI},
note={Online; abgerufen am 16.04.2023}
}

@misc{bundesministerium1,
title={TEAMWORK: Krisensimulation für die Zusammenarbeit von Einsatzkräften und Bevölkerung},
url={https://www.sifo.de/sifo/de/projekte/schutz-und-rettung-von-menschen/erhoehung-der-resilienz/teamwork/teamwork_node.html},
author={{Bundesministerium für Bildung und Forschung}},
note={Online; abgerufen am 16.04.2023}
}

@misc{kite,
title={Kite - KI-unterstütztes VR-Taktiktraining für polizeiliche Einsatzkräfte},
url={https://www.etit.tu-darmstadt.de/serious-games/forschung_und_projekte_sg/projekte_sg/KITE.de.jsp},
author={{Serious Games-Technische Universität Darmstadt}},
note={Online; abgerufen am 20.04.2023}
}

@misc{teamworkprojekt,
title={Teamwork},
url={https://www.teamworkprojekt.de/www.teamworkprojekt.de/html/projekt.html},
author={Teamwork},
note={Online; abgerufen am 19.04.2023}
}

@misc{Police1,
title={Police1},
url={https://www.police1.com/police-products/training/simulator/},
author={Police1},
note={Online; abgerufen am 01.05.2023}
}

@misc{VirTra300,
title={Virtra V-300},
url={https://www.virtra.com/simulator/law-enforcement-v-300/},
author={VirTra},
year={2023},
note={Online; abgerufen am 01.05.2023}
}

@article{davies2015hidden,
title={The hidden advantage in shoot/don't shoot simulation exercises for police recruit training},
author={Davies, Amanda},
journal={Salus journal},
volume={3},
number={1},
pages={16--30},
year={2015}
}

@misc{VirTra_yt_police,
title={Virtra V-300® | O’Fallon Police Department},
url={https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q153C5HR7r8&t=1s},
author={VirTra},
year={2022},
note={Online; abgerufen am 02.05.2023}
}

@article{binsubaih2009serious,
title={Serious games for the police: Opportunities and challenges},
author={BinSubaih, Ahmed and Maddock, S and Romano, D},
journal={Special Reports & Studies Series at the Research & Studies Center (Dubai Police Academy)},
year={2009},
publisher={Citeseer}
}

@misc{Curtis_2018,
title={First-person shooter: My experience training in a VirTra virtual reality simulator},
url={https://www.police1.com/police-products/firearms/training/articles/first-person-shooter-my-experience-training-in-a-virtra-virtual-reality-simulator-RK97iEFIunGY28lj/},
author={Curtis, Sean},
year={2018},
month={Sep},
note={Online; abgerufen am 05.05.2023}
}

@article{nopainnogain,
title={No pain, no gain? The effects of adding a pain stimulus in virtual training for police officers},
author={Kleygrewe, Lisanne and Hutter, RI and Oudejans, Raôul RD},
journal={Ergonomics},
pages={1--14},
year={2023},
publisher={Taylor & Francis}
}

@misc{Patrol_Officers,
title={Das neue Spiel ist endlich da!},
url={https://www.patrol-officers.com/de-DE/},
author={patrol-officers.com},
note={Online; abgerufen am 03.05.2023}
}

@misc{Apex_Officer_home,
title={Apex officer - virtual reality police training simulator},
url={https://www.apexofficer.com/},
author={Apex Officer},
note={Online; abgerufen am 15.05.2023}
}

@misc{Apex_Officer_packages,
title={VR police training packages},
url={https://www.apexofficer.com/packages},
author={Apex Officer},
note={Online; abgerufen am 21.05.2023}
}

@misc{Apex_Officer_Platform,
title={Virtual reality police training platform},
url={https://www.apexofficer.com/platform},
author={Apex Officer},
note={Online; abgerufen am 15.06.2023}
}

@misc{Hatch_2021,
title={How Virtra’s branching scenarios dramatically improve judgmental use of force for law enforcement},
url={https://www.virtra.com/how-virtras-branching-scenarios-improve-use-of-force/},
publisher={VirTra},
author={Hatch, Emily},
year={2021},
month={Oct},
note={Online; abgerufen am 29.05.2023}
}

@misc{Nelson_2023,
title={The tree of scenarios: Why branching scenarios help learning},
url={https://www.virtra.com/the-tree-of-scenarios-branching-instructor-led-scenarios-blog-2/},
journal={The Tree of Scenarios Why Branching InstructorLed Scenarios Help Learning Comments},
author={Nelson, Niki},
year={2023},
month={May},
note={Online; abgerufen am 10.06.2023}
}

@misc{VirTra_Author,
title={Strafverfolgung V-Author},
url={https://www.virtra.com/tool/strafverfolgung-v-author/?lang=de},
author={VirTra},
year={2020},
month={Oct},
note={Online; abgerufen am 10.06.2023}
}

@misc{VirTra_Rückstoßkits,
title={Rückstoßkits für die Strafverfolgung},
url={https://www.virtra.com/tool/rueckstosskits-fuer-die-strafverfolgung/?lang=de},
author={VirTra},
year={2020},
month={Oct},
note={Online; abgerufen am 11.06.2023}
}

@misc{VirTra_Threatfire,
title={Threat-Fire für die Strafverfolgung},
url={https://www.virtra.com/tool/threat-fire-fuer-die-strafverfolgung/?lang=de},
author={VirTra},
year={2020},
month={Oct},
note={Online; abgerufen am 11.06.2023}
}

@misc{Virtra_zubehör,
url={https://www.virtra.com/tool/zubehoer-fuer-die-strafverfolgung/?lang=de},
year={2020},
author={VirTra},
month={Oct},
note={Online; abgerufen am 11.06.2023}
}

@misc{VirTra_Wenigertödlich,
url={https://www.virtra.com/tool/strafverfolgung-weniger-toedlich/?lang=de},
author={VirTra},
year={2021},
month={Nov},
note={Online; abgerufen am 11.06.2023}
}

@misc{Virtra_vs_chimeaxr,
title={A tale of two simulators: Virtra 300 vs chimeraxr mythos},
url={https://www.recoilweb.com/a-tale-of-two-simulators-virtra-300-vs-chimeraxr-mythos-172299.html},
author={RECOIL - Firearm Lifestyle Magazine},
year={2022},
month={Jan},
note={Online; abgerufen am 11.06.2023}
}

@misc{Gould_Brothers_2021,
title={Virtual shooting simulator defense training at vortex edge},
url={https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApGEAmOMYPo&t=518s},
publisher={YouTube},
author={Gould Brothers},
year={2021},
month={Jul},
note={Online; abgerufen am 17.06.2023}
}

@misc{Admin_2023,
title={What is hit factor and how is it calculated and measured?},
url={https://pistolshootingsports.com/blog/hit-factor},
author={Pistol Shooting Sports},
year={2023},
month={Apr},
note={Online; abgerufen am 17.06.2023}
}

@misc{Gamestar,
author={Schwarz, Christian},
title={Police Simulator im Test: Endlich mal kein Berufssimulator zum Fremdschämen},
year={2022},
url={https://www.gamestar.de/artikel/police-simulator-test-steam-review,3386636.html},
note={Online; abgerufen am 26.06.2023}
}

@misc{Spieletester,
author={Jozi, Sina},
title={Police Simulator Patrol Officers (PC) Test},
year={2023},
url={https://www.spieletester.de/police-simulator-patrol-officers-testbericht/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 26.06.2023}
}

@misc{game7days,
author={Matthias, Anton},
title={Police Simulator: Patrol Officers – Test / Review (PC)},
year={2022},
url={https://game7days.de/2022/12/05/police-simulator-patrol-officers-test-review-pc/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 26.06.2023}
}

@misc{dualshockers,
author={Harding, Chris},
title={Police Simulator: Patrol Officers Review},
year={2022},
url={https://www.dualshockers.com/police-simulator-patrol-officers-ps5-review/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 26.06.2023}
}

@misc{Zotac,
author={Zotac},
title={VR GO 4.0 Backpack PC | ZOTAC},
year={o.D.},
url={https://www.zotac.com/de/page/zotac-vr-go-4},
note={Online; abgerufen am 27.06.2023}
}

@misc{HP_Backpack,
author={notebooksbilliger},
title={OMEN X by HP Compact Desktop mit VR Backpack P1000-030ng Intel i7-7820HK, 16GB RAM, 512GB SSD, GeForce GTX 1080, Win10 bei notebooksbilliger.de},
year={o.D.},
url={https://www.notebooksbilliger.de/omen+x+by+hp+compact+desktop+mit+vr+backpack+p1000+030ng+330749},
note={Online; abgerufen am 27.06.2023}
}

@misc{Linkbox,
author={Vive},
title={Das Headset an einen Computer anschließen},
year={o.D.},
url={https://www.vive.com/de/support/vive/category_howto/connecting-the-headset-to-your-computer.html},
note={Online; abgerufen am 27.06.2023}
}

@misc{Basestation,
author={Jaros, Garret},
title={Police academy in Mancos unveils new virtual reality training simulator},
year={2023},
url={https://www.durangoherald.com/articles/police-academy-in-mancos-unveils-new-virtual-reality-training-simulator/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 27.06.2023}
}

@misc{Basestation_Vive,
author={Vive},
title={Über die VIVE Basisstationen},
year={o.D.},
url={https://www.vive.com/de/support/vive/category_howto/about-the-base-stations.html},
note={Online; abgerufen am 27.06.2023}
}

@misc{VivePro,
author={Vive},
title={The professional-grade VR headset | VIVE Pro Deutschland},
year={o.D.},
url={https://www.vive.com/de/product/vive-pro/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 27.06.2023}
}

@misc{Vive_Tracker,
author={Vive},
title={VIVE Tracker (3.0) | VIVE Deutschland},
year={o.D.},
url={https://www.vive.com/de/accessory/tracker3/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 27.06.2023}
}

@misc{ApexOfficer_Recoil,
author={Apex Officer},
title={Apex Officer VR Training Simulator for Police Officers and Law Enforcement Agencies},
year={2020},
url={https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ggwneJMHblg},
note={Online; abgerufen am 07.07.2023}
}

@misc{LAPD,
author={{O’Neill, Maire}},
title={LAPD’s New Apex Officer Virtual Reality Training Simulator Is Both Futuristic And Realistic},
year={2021},
url={https://losalamosreporter.com/2021/05/30/lapds-new-apex-officer-virtual-reality-training-simulator-is-both-futuristic-and-realistic/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 07.07.2023}
}

@misc{monmouth,
author={{Monmouth County Sheriffs Office}},
title={Monmouth County Sheriff’s Office First In NJ To Use The Latest High Tech Virtual Reality Training For Officers},
year={2021},
url={https://www.mcsonj.org/sheriffs-office-first-in-nj-to-use-latest-high-tech-virtual-reality-training-for-officersrecognizes-national-alzheimers-disease-awareness-month-through-project-lifesaver-program-3/},
note={Online; abgerufen am 08.07.2023}
}

@misc{Virtra_youtube,
author={{VirTra}},
title={VirTra},
year={2023},
url={https://www.youtube.com/@VirtraSystems},
note={Online; abgerufen am 14.07.2023}
}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome to this site (2) Take your time to understand what is a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)  an why you should post a MWEB, not a long database  (3) at fist glance your references have several errors.  Sure that you know that some special characters cannot type "as is" in LaTeX (otherwise, try to compile a document with only the text "Hello & World" and see what happen) and the same apply to the referenced fields.

Comment: I highly recommend using a tool like BibTeX Tidy. There is an excellent online implementation at https://flamingtempura.github.io/bibtex-tidy

Answer (score 1):

The compilation issue is not related to BibTeX or biblatex *per se*. Instead, it arises because of a failure to "escape" several instances of the TeX-special character `&` in two bibliographic fields. By "escaping", I mean prefixing `\` ("backslash") to the TeX-special character. (Some other TeX-special characters are `#`, `$`, and `%`.)

To remedy the situation, you need to

- replace

  ```
  journal={Special Reports & Studies Series at the Research & Studies Center (Dubai Police Academy)},
  ```

  with

  ```
  journal={Special Reports \& Studies Series at the Research \& Studies Center (Dubai Police Academy)}
  ```
- replace

  ```
  publisher={Taylor & Francis}
  ```

  with

  ```
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
  ```

A separate comment: In case you don't already do so, be sure to load the `xurl` package so that long URL strings can be line-broken automatically, as needed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I used your solution but I am still getting the same error. Do you know what else might be the problem?

Comment: @flips89 - My answer was based on the sample bib entries posted in your query. If the real bib file contains other instances of TeX-special characters, further "escapement" operations will certainly be needed. A separate question: are there any TeX-special characters elsewhere in your document? If that's the case, they'll have to be escaped as well.